# Code is taking effect when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where if the user clicks on a button, it will display a value in the textbox and it will perform a trigger to another function after a '#btn' button is clicked:

```
function addwindow(numberAnswer, gridValues, btn) { 
    $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer).data('data-ignore',true);
    $('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');       
 }
```

Now what I want to do is that:

1. if the user clicked on the "Add" button, then display the number from the "Number of Answers" column into the textbox or in other words perform this from the `addwindow()` function:

   `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer).data('data-ignore',true);`
2. If the user has clicked on a `#btn+gridValues` button, then display the number in the textbox of the number of buttons which are currently turned on or in other words perform this code:

   `if ($('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').data('data-ignore') != true) {
       $('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : 0);
   }`

The problem is that step 1 works fine, it does display the number from the "Number of Answers" column in the textbox after the user has clicked on the "Add" button.

The problem is step 2, it is not displaying the correct number on how many buttons are currently turned on after the user has clicked on the `#btn+gridValues` button.It just doesn't change the number in the textbox.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how thi can be fixed?

DEMO:

Here is a [demo](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text14.php) of the application. Please follow the steps below:

Step 1: On left hand side you will see a green plus button, click on it and it opens up a modal window.
Step 2: In modal window there is a search bar, type in "AAA" and submit search, you will see a bunch of rows appear.
Step 3: In the last row, you see under "Number of Answer" colum that it contains the number 4, click on the "Add" button within this row, the modal window will close.

You will see that the textbox displays the number 4 in the textbox which is fine as that was the number within the row under the "Number of Answers" column when you added the row.

But below is the problem:

Step 4: If you click on the "Open Grid" link and select button 3, you will see the letter buttons below change to A-C with only letter "B" turned on.

In the textbox it should display number 1 as only 1 button is turned on, but it doesn't display this number and that is the problem I am having.

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure the data-ignore check is made on the right element? And could you provide more HTML?

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in the second code block. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Inkbug Sorry bout that, I pasted wrong code, I pasted the code before i sorted out the syntax error. I have updated that code which now doesn't provide the syntax error but still got the problem as explained in question

Comment: @Py. Which html do you want to see? it should be in the right element

Comment: Would it be possible to make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact taht you're setting the data-attribute to false on the `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt')` but you're checking against the inputs (`this` in the click).

One solution would be to do the following test `if ($('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').attr('data-ignore') != true)`

**EDIT**

To ensure that the ignore process execute only once (when the grid is reloaded after the modal), you'll have to change what's inside the block after the test:

```
if ($('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').data('ignore') != true) {
    $('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : 0);
} else {
    /*reset the ignore flag*/
    $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').data('ignore',false);
}
```

**EDIT2**

The main problem is that your reaffecting the `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer)` after setting it. Your trying to ignore it through the `ignore`attribute.

What i would adivse, would be to remove every occurence to that attribute and to change the following function

```
function addwindow(questionText,textWeight,numberAnswer,gridValues,reply,btn) {
    var answers = $.map(btn.split(''),function(chr){ return "#answer"+chr; }).join(', ');
    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') {
        var myNumbers = {};
        myNumbers["A-C"] = "3";
        myNumbers["A-D"] = "4";
        myNumbers["A-E"] = "5";
        myNumbers["A-F"] = "6";
        myNumbers["A-G"] = "7";
        gridValues = myNumbers[gridValues];
        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').show();
        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer).data('ignore',true);
        $('#mainGridTxt').val(gridValues).parent().append($('.optionTypeTbl'));
        $('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');
        $('.answers.answerBtnsOn').removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
        $(answers).addClass("answerBtnsOn").siblings().addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }
    $.modal.close();
    return false;
}
```

to :

```
function addwindow(questionText,textWeight,numberAnswer,gridValues,reply,btn) {
    var answers = $.map(btn.split(''),function(chr){ return "#answer"+chr; }).join(', ');
    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') {
        var myNumbers = {};
        myNumbers["A-C"] = "3";
        myNumbers["A-D"] = "4";
        myNumbers["A-E"] = "5";
        myNumbers["A-F"] = "6";
        myNumbers["A-G"] = "7";
        gridValues = myNumbers[gridValues];
        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').show();
        $('#mainGridTxt').val(gridValues).parent().append($('.optionTypeTbl'));
        $('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');
        /* moved the following line below the click simulation, 
           hence its value will be changed regardless of what happened during the click simulation*/
        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);
        $('.answers.answerBtnsOn').removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
        $(answers).addClass("answerBtnsOn").siblings().addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }
    $.modal.close();
    return false;
}
```

In order to modify the value after the visual changes took place.

Comment: If I do this then it displays he number in the textbox form the "Number of Answers" column, but then when in future if I want it to display how many buttons are turned on, it doesn't do that as when it ignores first code, it doesn't reach second code

Comment: I will test it in an hour because I have to run an errand but I will get back to you in about an hour :)

Comment: Now it doesn't display the correct number from the "Number of Answers" coulmn after the user has clicked on the "Add" button. Demo updated

Comment: Ok, I dived a little bit more into your code, that should do it (edit incoming).

Comment: I will give you bonty points when it lets me in 20 hours, why 20 hours I don't know but it has to be over 20 hours

Answer (score 0):

Use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `attr` - `attr` takes a string, `data` takes JavaScript objects.

Comment: I tried the data method but still no luck it is still displaying incorrect number in textbox because of second block of code is taking affect. I wil update question to show you application and steps to follow so you can see what is happening